# HAving issue with Test.isRunningTest()

Tags: apex, callout

I have a class and test class that worked fine.

```
Global class CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate{

public static Account accounts {get;set;}
public static String myresponse{get;set;}

webservice static string ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate(String id) {

    ABCWebServiceAccountUpdateAsync(id);
    return myresponse;        
}


@future(Callout=true)
  static void ABCWebServiceAccountUpdateAsync(String id)  
   {
   System.debug(id); 
       accounts = [SELECT id,Partner_Type__c FROM Account WHERE id =:id];
         if(id != null )
           {
               HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
               Http http = new Http();
               req.setMethod('GET');

               String url = 'https://blabla/Services.asmx/UpdateAccount?accountId='+id;
               req.setEndpoint(url);

               HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);
               myresponse = resp.getBody();
         }
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class TestUpdateAccountABCWebService{

 @isTest
 static void CreateAccountTestWSData() {

    Account acct = new Account();

    acct.Name = 'Test WebService Account';
    acct.Type = 'Dealer / Distributor';
    acct.Partner_Type__c = 'Dealer';
    acct.ShippingPostalCode = '22601';
    acct.Tier__c ='Exclusive';
    acct.Status__c = 'Active';

    insert acct;  

    acct = [SELECT Id,Name ,Type ,Partner_Type__c ,ShippingPostalCode,Tier__c,Status__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:acct.ID AND Partner_Type__c= 'Dealer'];
    acct.ShippingPostalCode = '22603';
    update acct;

   Test.startTest() ;
   Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        string result;
        result = CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate.ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate(acct.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
}

public class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

}

Created another Class and test class and now I get the 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts'
Test Class

```
@isTest
private class TestMerchandiseController {
static testmethod void testM(){

    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name  = 'Test Account';
    a.Type ='Government ';
    insert a;

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
    MerchandisingController testMerch = new MerchandisingController (sc);

    PageReference pageRef = Page.Merchandising_V2; 
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',a.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    testMerch.merch.Merchandise__c= 'Trex Rod Rail Display';
    testMerch.merch.Merchandise_Category__c= 'Full Size(6ft)';
    testMerch.merch.Merchandise_SubCategory__c = 'Black/Black';
    testMerch.merch.Account__c = a.Id;
    Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2018, 2, 17);
    testmerch.merch.Date_Displayed__c = myDate;

    Test.StartTest(); 
    testMerch.save(); 
    Test.StopTest();


    testMerch.message='Error';
    ApexPages.Message[] messages = ApexPages.getMessages();
    System.assertEquals(1, messages.size());

}   
}
```

So I added this to the CallABC Class

```
webservice static string ABCWebServiceAccountUpdate(String id) {
if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
    ABCWebServiceAccountUpdateAsync(id);
    return myresponse;   
}   else{

return 'Dummry Resp' ;
}
```

This corrected the issue with the Testmerchandise Class but the Call ABC class now has no coverage.  I am assuming the issue is the 'TestUpdateAccountABCWebService' but I am not sure and could use some serious help.

Comment: This question demonstrates a complete lack of research. Simply googling *"'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts"* would have yielded quite numerous results. You have to use a mock.

Comment: Adrian, I have a Mock Class 'Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());'  I originally had it as a stand alone Class but I kept getting a Constructor error.  So I adde to the test class itself.

Comment: What does `testMerch` have to do with the rest of your post? If you set a mock within the transaction where you make the callout, you won't get the error. It's as simple as that.

Comment: The testmerch is test class for another class that inserts/updates the Account record.  And when I run the 'TestMerchandiseController' class I get the ''Methods defined as ....." error.  I believe I discovered the issue which is that I am calling the 'CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate' class in a Account Trigger on insert and update.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting **Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts'** error then you're calling mock webservice in wrong approach.

In order to avoid above error you added this condition **if(!Test.isRunningTest())** which will skip your future method to be getting called that's why your code coverage is zero

Please have a look at this example which might help you,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Answer (score -1):

Issue was resolved by modiying the Trigger that was referencing the CallABCWebServiceAccountUpdate Class.